# Installing a driver without saving the setup file locally

Tags: windows, drivers, google-drive

I have a network driver setup file on my Google Drive. I am working with a client, and I want to install the driver on his PC. I don't want the client to have access to the driver setup file though, for I fear that the client may install the driver on other PCs not authorized by me. So, in other words, I want to install the driver and then have the setup file just disappear. I understand that merely deleting the setup file is probably not sufficient, for there are recovery softwares that recover deleted material. So, what are my options here? Is it possible to run the driver setup from my Google Drive without ever copying the driver locally onto the client's machine?

Comment: Not really. And since the driver is installed, the driver files will be on their machine and can quite easily be copied to another machine if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to install the setup from the google drive, it will download the setup file into the downloads folder and it will install the program. So a copy of the setup file will be created in his system.

If you have access to his system for a while you can install a data shredding software on his machine. Once the data is shredded, it will be next to impossible to recover the data. A [link](http://pcsupport.about.com/od/toolsofthetrade/tp/free-data-destruction-software.htm) for some free data shredding tools available on the internet.